# JSP import third party does not exists

Tags: java, maven, jsp, google-app-engine

I'm triying to consume a WS in Java inside JSP file. For that, I imported org.apache.sling.commons.json.* like that:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.sling.commons.json.*" %>
```

In my pom.xml file I put this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.json</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I do mvn appengine:update appears this error always:

```
error: package org.apache.sling.commons.json does not exist
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.*;
^
1 error

Error Details:
oct. 23, 2015 11:23:47 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Finally I got it! This was ok

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.json</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>

But I wrote in wrong pom.xml file :(